# Retrieve all child values and display on text field / text view from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have successfully get all child values but seems unable to display onto a `textField` or `textView`

**Edit**

I copied the wrong view controller code! Apologies. please see Screenshot or Code

I am able to display all of the child values. But only able to fetch the most updated value which is "Yes"

### Screenshot

[image]

### Code

```
dataRef?.child("Users/\(userID)/Posts/").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { (snapshot) in
                        for snap in snapshot.children {

                        let userSnap = snap as! DataSnapshot
                        let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                        let getPost = userDict["getPost"] as! String
                            print("Share Post: \(getPost)")

                        self.myTextView.text = getPost
                    }
                })

Share Post: hello world !❤️❤️✅
Share Post: 
Share Post: Ok sure. !
Share Post: SURE THING !
Share Post: hello  
Share Post: yes
```

Comment: What you get in `print(getLinks)` ?

Comment: All these Child Values.

Share Post: hello world !❤️❤️✅
Share Post: 
Share Post: Ok sure. !
Share Post: SURE THING !
Share Post: hello  
Share Post: yes

Comment: So whats the Code for `cell for row at indexpath` ?  Also make sure your outlet is proper And assign `Delegate` and `Data Source` to the `tableView`.

Comment: I added the wrong code. updated my corrected one. Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the edits

```
var postsStr = ""
dataRef?.child("Users/\(userID)/Posts/").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { (snapshot) in
                    for snap in snapshot.children {

                    let userSnap = snap as! DataSnapshot
                    let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    let getPost = userDict["getPost"] as! String
                        print("Share Post: \(getPost)")
                    postsStr += "\(getPost) | "

                }
            })

         self.myTextView.text = postsStr
```